# HTTPS Headers Referer value

Tags: asp.net, https, iis-10

In my site(https://www.exmpale1.com) the request is coming from external site(https://outsidesite.com). There is a link in external site which redirects the user to my site. When request came to my site I am checking if the request is coming from external site or not by checking HTTPS headers Referer value in the Global.asax file Application_EndRequest method like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("Referer")[0].Contains("outsidesite")
```

This is working perfectly fine in the staging site and return true. The problem is in the production site where Referer value is coming as my own site i.e example1 when request come from external site. I cannot understand why the Referer is different in staging site and production site. My application is hosted in IIS(10.0.14393.0) server and it is using the asp.net 3.5.
I am trying to find out where this refer value set and why it is different in staging and production environment. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Referer header is usually set by the web browsers (and possibly altered by anything on the wire), so if you want to trace down further, you need to start from a browser's developer tools and IIS failed request tracing, which gives you hints from both ends.

Comment: If you want to find out the reason, you can refer to the suggestion of lex li, the Referer value can be modified in iis if you want to modify it.

Comment: @LexLi In the web browser developers tools https headers refer value is my own site i.e https://www.exmpale1.com instead of https://outsidesite.com. Where can I find the IIS failed request tracing logs?

Comment: @samwu where can I modify the refer value in iis?

Comment: You can learn about FRT from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: You can refer to this link: [Http Header in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/560231/http-header-in-iis.html).